# MySQL - Error fetching records. Access denied for user 'Save password'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in MySQL.
I use VsCode on Windows and copied the code at 9:23 on this Youtube tutorial:
[youtube] (https://youtu.be/Cz3WcZLRaWc?t=563)
Here is the code:

`CREATE TABLE Users(       id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,      email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,     bio TEXT,     country VARCHAR(2)    );`

When run, I am met with this error:

Error fetching records. Access denied for user 'Save password'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Source: SQLTools (Extension)

The output bar returns this message:

```
[1697130812674] INFO  (ext): EXECUTING COMMAND => sqltools.getConnections
[1697130812675] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/GetConnectionsRequest
[1697130812676] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/ConnectRequest
[1697130812677] INFO  (ls): Connection instance created for test.
ns: "conn-manager"
Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: authProtocol. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection
Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: enableSsl. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection
[1697130812680] ERROR (ls): {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"MySQL","driverOptions":{"mysqlOptions":        {"authProtocol":"default","enableSsl":"Disabled"}}},"name":"Error"}
ns: "conn"
[1697130812680] ERROR (ls): Connecting error: {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"MySQL","driverOptions":    {"mysqlOptions":{"authProtocol":"default","enableSsl":"Disabled"}}},"name":"Error"}
ns: "conn-manager"
[1697130812680] ERROR (ls): Open connection error
ns: "conn-manager"
[1697130812679] ERROR (ext): ERROR: Error fetching records. Access denied for user 'Save password'@'localhost' (using password: YES), {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"MySQL","driverOptions":{"mysqlOptions":{"authProtocol":"default","enableSsl":"Disabled"}}}}
    ns: "error-handler"
```

How can I fix this issue? The "Help!" button on VSCode opened this website https://vscode-sqltools.mteixeira.dev/connections/mysql#Error with page not found. Thank you very much, I hope you have a good day.

Comment: Sorry if this is not how we ask a question or if i did something wrong on the way I asked the question, I am new to stackoverflow and MySQL. Have a good day!

Comment: It sounds like you have the password where the username should be in your database settings.

Comment: Hello Mr. Barmar, since I do not know how to change the username or password, I completely deleted the MySQL from my computer and reinstalled it. I changed the password to something different, but still receive the same error message. What could be the cause? Thank you very much, and I hope you have a good day!

Comment: I'm talking about the settings in VSCode for accessing the database.

Comment: You have to provide correct user name and password for the connection to work. I don't think your mysql user is called "save password"

Comment: I suggest to you until you have the fundamentals of the language do not use VS Code or other IDE. For learning the basics the best tool is the simplest such as Notepad. 

Many newbies can code in VS Code (because this is one of the most popular IDE in tutorials) but if they enter a different environment they are stuck.

Comment: Hello, I went into the settings for the connection of the MySQL and these are the settings, I tried changing the username, but it did nothing:

Connection name*  MySQL Database Test
Connection group (This is empty)
Connect using*  Server and Port
Server Address*  localhost
Port*  3306
Database* William's Test Database
Username* William
Password mode SQLTOOLS Driver Credentials

MySQL driver specific options

Authentication Protocol  default
SSL Disabled
Connection Timeout (This is empty)
Show records default limit 50

Comment: Do you have a username called 'save password'?  If not then that's your problem.

Comment: Computer username or a username I would of written somewhere else? Thank you very much!

Comment: You do not need a computer user name. You only need mysql user name.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped me, the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The username inside of the connection settings should be the same as the MySQL username.
To find the username, run the MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, enter your MySQL password, and then run this command:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

This will return

```
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| username@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

And the username of the MySQL is what is right before the @localhost

So enter this on the VScode SQLTool settings, and it will work.